# log4j2 No appenders found for 1 logger

Tags: java, hibernate, log4j, log4j2

I'm having trouble configuring my log4j2.xml file to include hibernate logging.

Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="TRACE">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="logDir" value="${env:MY_APP}/logs"/>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="MY_APP" fileName="${logDir}/my_app.log" bufferedIO="true" filePattern="${logDir}/my_app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%t] %d %-5p %x %m%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy/>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
                <Delete basePath="${logDir}" maxDepth="1">
                    <IfFileName glob="my_app-*.log.gz" />
                    <IfLastModified age="31d" />
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
         </RollingFile>
     </Appenders>
     <Loggers>
         <Root level="trace">
             <AppenderRef ref="MY_APP" level="debug"/>
         </Root>
         <Logger name="com.company" level="info"/>
         <Logger name="com.companyName" level="info"/>
         <Logger name="com.companyName.myApp" level="debug"/>
         <Logger name="org.hibernate" level="info"/>
    </Loggers>
```

And on startup of my jar i get the following printed to the console:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger(org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

I seem to get logs from my application into my RollingFile but i can't understand why this hibernate logger isn't using the same appender.

Any help muchly appreciated!

Comment: To clarify you want hibernate to append to the same file?

Comment: @Ishnark correct, i want all of them to append to the same file

Comment: I think you have to tell the hibernate logger specifically to log to file. `<logger name="org.hibernate" level="info"><appender-ref ref="MY_APP"/></logger>`

Comment: @Ishnark sorry for the late reply, hmm that doesn't seem to work either, same warning message

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but mine was related to a specific class that I had created, not one that was in a library. However, what I found the error to be specifically for `log4j2` is that I was using the incorrect Logger.

My code use to be:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class SomeClass {
   static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SomeClass.class);
}
```

What ended up working for me was:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;

public class SomeClass {
   static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(SomeClass.class.getName());
}
```

**NOTE:** the difference in the imports and how the logger is "created".

This is what solved this exact error for me, but it wasn't in a library.

For me, I have Hibernate in my project too, but without any additional configuration Hibernate logs to all my appenders automatically. They might have fixed this in their updates to the package.

**SUGGESTION** (if not already fixed) - maybe try to upgrade the package/library for Hibernate and see if it works. Alternatively, see if you can find out how the logger is created so as to make use that it uses `org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger` INSTEAD of `org.apache.log4j.Logger`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the fact that the console shows

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger(org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

indicates that the log4j 1.x jars are still present on the classpath and no log4j 1.x configuration has been provided. The fix for this is to replace the log4j 1.x jar with the log4j-1.2-api jar from Log4j 2.